# jquery rateit get form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use rateit but I am not able to get selected value from form

```
<input class='center-block' type='range' max='5' step='1' id='rateit' name='rateit' />
<div class='rateit bigstars' data-rateit-backingfld='#rateit' id='rateit9' data-rateit-step='1' data-rateit-resetable='false' data-rateit-starwidth='32' data-rateit-starheight='32'></div>
```

It always return default value 3 from stars.

My jquery.rateit.js version is v1.0.22

What I doing wrong ?

Comment: That default actually came from input range. Default value for that object is 3. If I change rateit stars to 2 it won't change value in range element.

Comment: Could you please provide the JQuery code to get the selected star value.I tried this way,but i didn't get the value.                                   <span id="RateForm_15" class="rateit"></span>                                                   <script>var rateValue = $('#RateForm_15 > div').attr('aria-valuenow');</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have duplicate rateit element with same id in page. After I renamed elements it started to work.